# How to get access to "occult" function in R

Tags: r, function

Sometimes I see functions with occult functions. If you call these functions, `R` does not recognized them and throws an `Error`.

I was reading the code for `xgb.cv` function from `xgboost` R package and realized that they use a function (`generate.cv.folds`) and it seems that it is not "available". So I was wondering how they do it, and if is that possible to access this specific function.
The error message is the following:

```
#Error: object 'generate.cv.folds' not found
```

Thank you.

Comment: Access it using `xgboost:::generate.cv.folds`. A function like this is not exported, i.e. the package dev does not want you to use it in the first place, so be careful.

Comment: Thank you. And how you occult it when writing in your function?

Comment: I guess with *occult* you mean private or so? If a developers writes a package and does not `#' @export` a function, then the user (you) does not see it.

Comment: Perfect explanation!! Thank you @SimonDirmeier.

Comment: Marked as duplicate. See the excellent answers in the original link for a full in-depth explanation of how to access to functions and methods in R.

Comment: Thanx @nicola. I did now that post, but I miss the "Unexported functions" part.